# @Value for initializing java.util.Date in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, spring-3

I have a `Employee` class with a `java.util.Date` type member variable like this:

```
@Component(value="employeeBean")
public class Employee {
// How to initialize this using @Value ???
private Date dateOfJoining;
}
```

Using the `application context xml` this can be done using this:

```
<bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</bean>

<bean id="employeeBean" class="com.Employee">
    <property name="dateOfJoining">
        <bean factory-bean="dateFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="2010-01-31" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I want to do this using Annotations. Please advice.

Comment: @Value("#{employeeBean[dateOfJoining]}") it works ? i thinkg that value only works for properties, i never try for property beans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Value("#{dateFormat.parse('2010-01-31')}")
private Date dateOfJoining;
```

You can use [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) enclosed with `#{}` in `@Value` annotation

Answer (score 4):

If that can help other people :

```
    @Value("#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse('2010-01-31')}")
    private Date dateOfJoining;
```

Or, if the date string and date format are stored in a properties file:

application.properties :

```
date.of.joining=2010-01-31
date.of.joining.format=yyyy-MM-dd
```

Java class :

```
    @Value("#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('${date.of.joining.format}').parse('${date.of.joining.format}')}")
    private Date dateOfJoining;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Value(${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyyMMdd\").parse(\"${PROP_DATE}\")})
private Date dateOfJoining;

Comment: what is the use of `$` inside `@Value` in the above posted code? please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Add the import :

#### For DateTimeFormat

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
```

#### For more kind of validation like : NotNull

You can use validation-api jar , after including the jar just import :

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`;
```

And in the class , while defining variable :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
@NotNull
private Date date;
```